# Assigning retaining object to weak property; object will be released after assignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, delegates, weak

I wrote on Xcode6 the example of Objective-C delegation pattern on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Objective-C_example). Every time you set the delegate there is a Warning "Assigning retaining object to weak property; object will be released after assignment". After running the example, methods f and g of A class dont execute.
Changing the line

> @property (weak, nonatomic) id i; // delegation

to

> @property (strong, nonatomic) id i; // delegation

fix the problem. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in the delegate pattern you want the reference to be weak, because it refers to a delegate which is the *strong* property of another object.  Since these are generally *not* owned by the object that has the `delegate` property (`i` in your example), you don't want to keep a strong reference to them. In fact, it is quite common that you would have an object, such as a window controller (or navigation controller in iOS) that owns an object (such as a control of some kind) whose delegate you want to set back to the window controller (or navigation controller).

In this case, you need the `delegate` reference to be weak in order to prevent a retain loop (otherwise the window controller owns a reference to the control which owns a reference to the window controller as the delegate).

So, in your above example, you would be better off exploring this concept by using a more real-world example where the delegate itself is retained by another object, which more closely mirrors the way that delegates are used in the wild.